# adding passes to the passbook app from my app programmatically

Tags: passbook

I'm creating a passbook app but I want ot know if there is anyway that I can programmatically add the passes that I have in app to passbook app? I know that passes can be opened in the passbook app automatically but I want to know if I can control that from my app?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can! Everything you need is detailed in the Passbook Documentation available at https://developer.apple.com/passbook.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I went over Apple's documentations and videos. What I understood is that when you create an app using pssskit, passkit creates a view controller with and ADD button which allows you to add passes from your app to the passbook app. Is there any other way to this? Can I write my own code to that? is there any specific link in Apple's documentation where I can find that?